# PrimeNG p-table pagination dropdown list hidden on full screen mode

Tags: pagination, append, primeng, p-table

The codes are below:

```xml
<p-table
    [columns]="colsHistoryLogEntryList"
    [value]="entity.historyLogEntryList"
    [resizableColumns]="true"
    [autoLayout]="true"
    [paginator]="true"
    [rows]="5"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]"
    paginatorDropdownAppendTo="body"
    class="ui-table-historyEntry-list"
    [rowHover]="true"
>
```

When the page was maximized, the dropdown list is rendered to the bottom and it was partially hidden. But when the page was shrunk, it was rendered to the up direction correctly.

How can I force the dropdown list to be visible all the time?

[image: Click to show the screenshot]